# Multiple data types within one vector of pointers using templates

Tags: oop, templates, vector, c++14

I have two classes seen below,

```
template <typename T> class node   {
public:
    int NodeID;//ID used to identify node when inserting/deleting/searching
    T data;//generic data encapsulated in each node.
    std::vector<node*> children;//child nodes, list of ptrs
    std::vector<node*> parents;//parent nodes list of ptrs
};

template<typename T> class DAG {//Class for the graph

    std::vector<node<T>*> Nodes;//Vector of node ptrs, this is how we define a DAG;
}
```

I was wondering whether its possible using templates to have the vector of nodes contain nodes of multiple types? Something like this.

```
std::vector<node*> Nodes = {node<int>*,node<string>*, ...}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not use inheritance and virtual functions, which is basically the standard method to achieve runtime polymorphism in C++?

Comment: No no reason at all, could you explain to me how that would work ?

Comment: The answer below was quicker and shows what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use polymorphism and create a non-template base class:

```cpp
struct nodebase {
    nodebase(int id) : NodeID{id} {}
    virtual ~nodebase() = default; // to be able to delete via base class pointer

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << NodeID;
    }

    int NodeID;  // ID used to identify node when inserting/deleting/searching

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<nodebase>> children; // child nodes, list of ptrs
    std::vector<nodebase*> parents;  // parent nodes list of ptrs
};

// to be able to print all nodes, calls the overridden `print` method:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const nodebase& nb) {
    nb.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

With that base class, your `node<T>` could look like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class node : public nodebase {
public:
    // constructor taking `id` + the arguments needed for `T`:
    template<class... Args>
    node(int id, Args&&... args) : nodebase{id}, data{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

    void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        nodebase::print(os);
        os << ',' << data;
    }

    T data;  // generic data encapsulated in each node.
};
```

And you could use it like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<nodebase>> Nodes;

    Nodes.emplace_back(std::make_unique<node<int>>(1, 12356));
    Nodes.emplace_back(std::make_unique<node<std::string>>(2, "Hello world"));

    for(auto& ptr : Nodes) {
        std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1,12356
2,Hello world
```

Comment: Hi Ted sorry for the late reply, this was really helpful however I'm finding it impossible to use the 'children' and 'parents' vector within nodebase everytime I use emplace_back with either of them Im getting a compiler error.

Comment: @BenBorg I see. I just put `std::unique_ptr<nodebase>` in there to make the cleanup easier.. What happens if you go back to your original idea and replace `std::unique_ptr<nodebase>` with `nodebase*`?

Comment: I tried this `nodebase* A = new(nodebase(1)); ` however I get an error "Expected a type".

Comment: What if I want to decide what data I want to put into each node later. Can I just create a nodebase then downcast it to a node later?

Comment: @BenBorg Since `nodebase` is not abstract, you can create a `nodebase` object, but you can't cast it into something that it is not. You'll have to `delete` it and replace it with the object of your wanted type.

Comment: @BenBorg I realize I made a mistake in my comment above so I removed that comment. You should do `nodebase* A = new nodebase(1);` if you want an object with id `1` and `nodebase* A = new node<int>(1, 10);` if you want a node with id `1` and value `10`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240576/discussion-between-ben-borg-and-ted-lyngmo).